# Pushing cloned TFS repo to a private repo with history

Tags: git, tfs

I cloned a TFS repo using `git-tfs clone <tfs-url>` command to my local machine amd when its done, I opened the folder and do a git log and I could see all the beautiful history.

Now, when I create a new private repo and clone that repo to my local then copy paste all the objects from TFS (that i just cloned to my local) into the new repo and `git push` it, I dont see the beautiful history, only 1 history of me pushing it to the new repo. I need to have the old history from TFS repo intact. How do I do that?

Also, idk if it helps but when I opened the cloned TFS folder on my local machine and I do git remote -v, there is nothing no remote at all, its just empty, i thought `git-tfs clone` would add git remote automatically but it doesnt. Unlike `git clone` which automatically creates a remote connection called origin pointing back to the cloned repository as stated in [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=does%20git%20clone%20add%20remote&oq=do&aqs=chrome.1.69i60j69i59l2j69i60l5.1449j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvm found the answer

`git remote add <origin-url>`

`git push origin master`

Answer (score 0):

> Now, when I create a new private repo and clone that repo to my local then copy paste all the objects from TFS (that i just cloned to my local) into the new repo and git push it, I dont see the beautiful history, only 1 history of me pushing it to the new repo. I need to have the old history from TFS repo intact. How do I do that?

What you did is not pushing your history, but just committing the tip of your source code.

See what I have written in the git-tfs documentation to add a remote toward your newly created git repository and push the history :

https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md#add-a-remote-toward-git-central-repository

> Also, idk if it helps but when I opened the cloned TFS folder on my local machine and I do git remote -v, there is nothing no remote at all, its just empty, i thought git-tfs clone would add git remote automatically but it doesnt.

That's something that git-tfs can't do and makes no sense. Git-tfs does not know the newly created repository (and don't manage the TFVC link as a git remote to not confuse users).

Comment: thanks for replying, i saw your instruction and i tried to git remote add origin <tfs-url> but i got index.lock error, the index.lock file is only created when i tried to do that command, since i cant click yes, i have to click no and afterwards the index.lock dissapear. Tried to troubleshoot that, people said to kill ssh agent.exe and restart the VM, but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

> I need to have the old history from TFS repo intact.

For Git, just using the Import Repository feature, you can import a Git repository to your team project from other project's git repo. The newly imported repo will keep all commit history. For details, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops).

[image]

The import repo feature was introduced in TFS 2017 Update 1. If you are using TFS 2017 RTM or earlier, you can use the following steps to [manually import a repo into TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/import-git-repository?view=azure-devops#manually-import-a-repo).

```
git clone --bare {clone repo url}
cd repo name.git
git push --mirror {target repo url}
```

If you do not know the path, we can call the cmd `dir` to load the file list and then find the path.

[image]

Comment: the repo that im tryina import is 3 GB+ and the document on azure's website about using the direct import utility states that the repo must be less than 1 GB, so we cant go with that method